# Ubuntu 16.04 Critical Error

Tags: software-center, gdebi

I tried installing Zoom with software centre and it didn't install.work. I then tried to install gdebi with software centre and it didn't install either. I then tried to install gdebi in the terminal and got this message

> `The package skypeforlinux needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it`

I researched this and tried various solutions to remedy which are too numerous to remember but none worked. Now when I go to update manager I get this message

> `apt transaction returned result exit-failed`

So now I have 2 problems:
1) unable to install software and
2) unable to update ubuntu. Is this fixable?

---

```
~$ sudo apt update 
Hit:1 archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
Hit:2 ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
Get:3 ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB] 
Get:4 ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [109 kB] 
Get:5 ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Sources [347 kB] 
Get:6 ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [1,120 kB] 
Get:7 ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages [907 kB]
Get:8 ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages [795 kB] 
Get:9 ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages [721 kB] 
Fetched 4,108 kB in 2s (1,637 kB/s) 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done 
35 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them. 

~$ sudo apt upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
E: The package skypeforlinux needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Comment: Please open a terminal. Show us the complete output of `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: ~$ sudo apt update Hit:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Get:3 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]
Get:4 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [109 kB]
Get:5 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Sources [347 kB]
Get:6 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [1,120 kB]
Get:7 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages [907 kB]

Comment: Get:8 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages [795 kB]
Get:9 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages [721 kB]
Fetched 4,108 kB in 2s (1,637 kB/s)                      
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
35 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.

Comment: ~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package skypeforlinux needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

Answer (score 0):

At first remove the skypeforlinux package by

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-all skypeforlinux
```

then get all updates and install them

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and then resume installation of Zoom.

Comment: I tried this and got following message: $ sudo apt-get purge skypeforlinux
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package skypeforlinux needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package skypeforlinux needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

Comment: Then try `sudo dpkg -P skypeforlinux`.

Comment: doesn't look too healthy: dpkg: error processing package skypeforlinux (--purge):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
Errors were encountered while processing:
 skypeforlinux. I wonder should I remove skype completely? Is skype the only problem?

Comment: Skype prevents installation of other applications as you see. Final method is to use `sudo rm  /var/lib/dpkg/info/skypeforlinux.*`.

Comment: No joy: rm: cannot remove '/var/lib/dpkg/info/skypeforlinux': No such file or directory

Comment: This command worked: sudo dpkg --remove --force-all skypeforlinux. Thanks for your help.